# How can I print a list of table names gathered by a certain prefix with MySqli and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve a list of all tables inside my database with the prefix 'CMS_'

The Code I am working with right now is:

```
$DB->conn = new mysqli($DB->servername, $DB->username, $DB->password, $DB->database);
if(!$DB->conn->connect_errno){
  $recordset = $DB->conn->query("SELECT * FROM `TABLES` WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'CMS_*' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='$DB->database'");
  if($recordset->num_rows < 1){echo ("<H2>You have no Content-Types Defined...</H2>");}
  else{
    $recordset = $recordset->fetch_array();
    foreach($recordset as $record){
    var_dump($record);echo "<BR/>";
    }
  }
}else{die("fatal error;no database connection;");}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL You should use wildcard `%` instead of `*`

```
LIKE 'CMS_%'
```

---

EDIT:

```
while($record = $recordset->fetch_array()){
   var_dump($record);echo "<BR/>";
}
```

Comment: I changed my statement to "SHOW TABLES LIKE 'CMS_%' and now the query only returns the first result. If I run the same query in phpMyAdmin it loads the full set. I still can't figure this out.